# Java REST API GET test

Tags: java, testing, quarkus

im wondering how to test GET given below. I don't have much experience with testing so would be glad if some 1 could show me proper approach or comment what should i do better.

```
@Path("/some")
public class SomeApi {

    @Inject
    SomeLogic someLogic;

    @GET
    @Produces({"application/json;charset=utf-8","application/json"})
    @RolesAllowed("ek_external")
    public Response getSome(@QueryParam("id") Long id, @QueryParam("name") String name, @Min(0) @DefaultValue("0") @QueryParam("offset") Integer offset, @Min(1) @Max(50) @DefaultValue("20") @QueryParam("limit") Integer limit, @Context SecurityContext securityContext) {
        return someLogic.getSome(id, name, offset, limit, securityContext);
    }
}
```

This is my GET. Im not sure how to handle all these QueryParams and annotated args.

Im trying something like this

```
@QuarkusTest
public class SomeApiTest {

    @Test
    public void testGetSome() {
        given()
                .when().get("/some")
                .then()
                .statusCode(200)
                .body()
    }
}
```

i ll be glad for showing me which way to go :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The example in the documentation here: https://quarkus.io/guides/getting-started-testing#recap-of-http-based-testing-in-jvm-mode suggests the only thing missing might be setting the body... `...(200).body(is(someBody))`.

The example given here: https://quarkus.io/guides/getting-started-testing#restassured also looks relevant.

Also ensure you provide `@TestConfiguration` so that when you `@Inject` the class for `SomeLogic`, it is not `null`.

Comment: I ll try it out tomorrow (same for POST) and see how it goes. Thanks :)